# How to get a person telegram link by only his phone number via API?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram-api

Is there a way to get person's telegram via API or telegram bot by only his phone number and not adding him into contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is No, you have to add it to your contacts.

Recently Telegram introduced ["Phone Number Links"](https://telegram.org/blog/downloads-attachments-streaming#phone-number-links), something similar to what you have asked for, but unfortunately it only works for the numbers that you already have in your contacts or for the users that have their privacy phone number settings set public.

for example: https://t.me/+42777

Comment: Thank you for the info. I really appreciate it.